# thevenin equivalence of wheatstone bridge load

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm trying to figure out the Thevenin equivalent as seen from the load of a wheatstone bridge... however, I think the model example in the book is wrong:

**Here's what the book has to say:**

[image: book says this]

---

---

**Here's my work:**

[image: I say this]

Which is the right answer?

Comment: You are correct, \$R_{eq}=R_1||R_3+R_2||R_4\$

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are.  They're making an algebraic error, assuming that adding conductances is the same as adding the associated resistances (initial equation is wrong).  They further compound it by combining parallel resistors wrongly...the parallel resistances should each have their own reciprocol, not share the same denominator.

Answer (score 1):

The example solution is wrong.

They wrote \$\frac1{R_{_\text{TH}}}=\frac1{R_1+R_3}+\frac1{R_2+R_4}\$ when they should have written \$R_{_\text{TH}}=\frac1{\frac1{R_1}+\frac1{R_3}}+\frac1{\frac1{R_2}+\frac1{R_4}}\$. Note that in the correct form (the latter), the conductances at each end of the load are first added together (correct to do) and then converted separately to equivalent resistance values at either end (correct to do), which can then be added to make up the total Thevenin resistance that the load "sees."

They just messed up, thinking that the resistances can be directly added, instead. They cannot be. Only the conductances can be added.

What you did works just fine.

---

But let's use nodal analysis, just to double check. And to completely mix things up, let's re-arrange the circuit to look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fenL9a.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here, if we leave \$R_{\text{LOAD}}\$ disconnected I find that \$V_X=-1.25\:\text{V}\$. And if I short out \$R_{\text{LOAD}}\$, then I find that the current in the shorting wire is \$I_X=-\frac5{14}\:\text{A}\$. This means that \$V_{\text{TH}}=V_X=-1.25\:\text{V}\$ and that \$R_{\text{TH}}=\frac{-1.25\:\text{V}}{-\frac5{14}\:\text{A}}=-\frac72\:\Omega\$. Same deal. (I avoided showing the nodal math. But you can work it out, I'm sure.)

---

Yet another way to look at the above schematic without using nodal is like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNwF9j.png)</sup>

Here, you obviously have two simple resistive voltage dividers. Clearly, \$V_C=V_Y+\frac{R_3}{R_1+R_3}\,V_S\$ and \$V_D=V_Y+\frac{R_4}{R_2+R_4}\,V_S\$. (Because \$\left[V_Y+V_S\right] - \left[V_Y\right]=V_S\$.)

The difference between these must be \$V_D-V_C=V_Y+\frac{R_4}{R_2+R_4}\,V_S-\left(V_Y+\frac{R_3}{R_1+R_3}\,V_S\right)\$ or \$V_\text{TH}=V_D-V_C=\left(\frac{R_4}{R_2+R_4}-\frac{R_3}{R_1+R_3}\right)\,V_S=\left(\frac{6\:\Omega}{9\:\Omega}-\frac{6\:\Omega}{8\:\Omega}\right)\,15\:\text{V}=-1.25\:\text{V}\$.

And you've already worked out what happens when you short out \$R_L\$, correctly. So you have \$R_\text{TH}\$, too.